# How to combine two SCORM 2004 modules

Tags: scorm, scorm2004

Suppose I have two SCORM 2004 modules - instruction.zip and test.zip. The first contains instructional web pages and the second contains an interactive quiz. Each package was authored separately. I want to combine them to create a single course of study in which students read the web pages and then test their knowledge. (I will leave to one side the significant issues of sequencing and navigation.)

What is the recommended way of combining the two? I have tried (i) merging the two (did not work due to differences in file structure and dependencies) and (ii) adding test.zip to instruction.zip as a complete package and adding links (issues with reporting of test results).

I realise that most people author their courses using Captivate or other software to produce an single integrated package. For reasons that need not be discussed here, that is not an option in my case: the test assets will be developed separately and need to be combined with the instructional assets.

Comment: There is no automated way of doing it. You need to unzip, put all files into the same directory, and create a multisco manifest that describes the new setup. That's as specific as I can get without seeing your projects myself.

Answer (score 0):

Grant,
I've got a packager on my site https://cybercussion.com which may be able to help you.  If there is any advanced features your using though I haven't built out support for that yet.  There is a 30 day trial for it.

You'd just need to expand the content into something like:

```
Multi-SCO/
    SCO Title 1/ [all SCO 1 files]
    SCO Title 2/ [all SCO 2 files]
```

You can also do this by hand by merging the imsmanifest organization markup together which if your friendly with XML is a option.  You'll just need to manage the organization and resource elements.  You also may have DTD/XSDs apart of both packages.

Manually zipping this yourself could result in a error importing on the LMS.  Some platforms expect the imsmanifest.xml to be in the root of the zip and if its inside a folder it could error.  So watch out for that.

Answer (score 0):

We have some great SCORM 2004 samples on our site that may serve as a guide for you as far as sequencing and navigation goes.  Check out the golf samples [here](http://scorm.com/scorm-explained/technical-scorm/golf-examples/.)

If you have any questions, please let us know!

Joe Donnelly
support@scorm.com